# IntelliJ Whitespace formatting

Tags: git, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

I'm having issues with using IntelliJ on an Electron project that I'm working on. I'm using IntelliJ on a Mac while others in the team use Visual Studio Code on Windows. I get excessive whitespace reformatting in any file I touch and I'm wondering how to prevent IntelliJ reformatting. Is there an easy switch or option I can enable/disable to fix this? I'm also wondering if this has anything to do with Windows CRLF characters. The project is maintained in a git repo and I thought either git or VSCode would be smart enough to normalize whitespace per platform.

Comment: Yes, it's a CR/LF problem. You can fix it in a number of ways. It's possible to let git normalize the line endings, but it might be easier for you to just configure your IDE. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/handling-lf-and-crlf-line-endings.html

Comment: Thanks I'll try this...